# Python transposing a row list to a column list

Tags: python, list, numpy, pyqt, ipython

Being relatively new to python I have a problem that I cant seem to easily solve (or completely understand)
Running the followin code:

```
(" ".join(map(str,np.int32(((np.arange(14))))))).split()
```

produces the following:

```
Out[54]: ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13']
```

whereas

```
(" ".join(map(str,np.int32(((np.arange(15))))))).split()
```

produces the following

```
Out[2]: 
['0',
 '1',
 '2',
 '3',
 '4',
 '5',
 '6',
 '7',
 '8',
 '9',
 '10',
 '11',
 '12',
 '13',
 '14']
```

I would like to be able to create a list in form of a column instead of a row using less than 15 numbers.

Does anyone have any help to offer on this?

The reason for this is that QtWidgets.QCombobox.additems('list of strings') chashes the console/kernel if in the case with 14 but not with 15 (or greater).

(using spyder 3.6 / ipython 3.6.2 / anaconda (4.4, 64bit) / pyqt 5.6.2 on windows 7)

EDIT 1:
thanks a lot for the replies.. however..  `map(str, np.int32(np.arange(14)))` produces `Out[4]: <map at 0xba4f2b0>`.

Suddenly it worked with less than 15 items in the list. It seems more and more like the problem with pyqt/ QCombobox is some random error (when there are too many comboboxes or something.. ... another question probably.

Comment: Both lists have the same "form", that is just IPython displaying it differently when it doesn't fit in one line.

Comment: In Python 3.x, `map` returns a map object and not a sequence unless materialised... Use a simple and explicit list comprehension instead (no need for numpy, joining then splitting back strings etc...), eg: `items = [str(i) for i in range(14)]` and pass that to your combo box

Comment: "Suddenly it worked with less than 15 items in the list." Maybe you changed something in your code. Without a minimal example, we will never know if there is a bug in PyQt or if you accidentally fixed a bug in your program and how. This makes the question not very useful for others.

Comment: @JonClements. FWIW, `QCombobox.additems` works fine with any kind of iterable, including a `map` object. I tried all the examples shown in the question, and they all work fine for me. Seems to be a classic case of PEBKAC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of, you can get rid of a lot of parenthesis. You can write:

```
(" ".join(map(str,np.int32(((np.arange(14))))))).split()
```

as

```
(" ".join(map(str, np.int32(np.arange(14))))).split()
```

The `" ".join()` and `.split()` are the exact opposite, so you could get rid of them too without effect.

```
map(str, np.int32(np.arange(14))
```

The difference you see is that the list of 15 numbers is *displayed* as rows whereas the list of 14 numbers is *displayed* as columns. Internally, there is no difference.
When you want to display each number on a new line, you can simply join the numbers using the newline character:

```
"\n".join(map(str, np.int32(np.arange(14)))
```

If you insist on the colons and brackets you can do it like this:

```
print("[%s]" % ",\n ".join(map(str, np.int32(np.arange(14)))))
```

Comment: In fact - the use of numpy and the joining and splitting stuff can all go... `items = [str(i) for i in range(14)]` should be sufficient

Comment: Or, if you start with a numpy array, `list(np.arange(14).astype(str))`